# Flex CategoryAxis with non-unique values

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, charts

I have a BarChart that compares different user interactions with a program we have. Obviously some users will have multiple sessions and depending on what the filtering is, a single user may have multiple entries displayed at once.

The problem comes in with the Category Axis, which uses the username as the categoryField. This is fine and displays nicely when there are no repeats of the username in the dataset.  If there are repeats, though, it will put a new entry in the Y axis for each instance of the username, but all of the data is rendered on the first label in the Y axis.

Is there any way to keep the username as the category axis, but have the BarChart display the corresponding data in the correct spots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different internal name. Then use a custom labelFunction to allow duplicate label values.

Comment: It's not ideal, but it does work.  I ended up adding a uid for each session tracked, and use that as the Y axis category.